# How to set a word count in a text file

Tags: python

I need to find the number of words in a file. Any sequence of alphanumeric characters with a length >= 1 and with the beginning and ending non-alphanumeric character removed counts as a word.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
num_words = 0

textfile = open('gettysburg.txt', 'r').read()
words = textfile.split()
for word in words:
   if len(word) >= 1:
     num_words +=1

 print(num_words)
```

The counter gives me 268, but there are 271 words in the text. There are four words that are separated by dashes or "--" which are being counted as 2 words. How do I strip the non-letter characters to display these 4 words?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to strip the hyphens, you just want them noted as characters that can make a word. You might use a regular expression.

```
re.findall('[\w\-]+', 'words in sentence. some hyphenated-together.')
```

gives

```
['words', 'in', 'sentence', 'some', 'hyphenated-together']
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you are incredibly close.

The `string.split()` function takes a parameter `str` which by default is white-space.
You can also change the letter that the string should be split by.

```
num_words = 0
textfile = open('gettysburg.txt', 'r').read()
words = textfile.split()
for word in words:
   count = len(word.split(str = "-"))
   num_words += count
print(num_words)
```

[Python Tutorials](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) has a nice description about the function.